# Dropdown PageSize selection in ASP.NET Core with PagedList problem

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to add a dropdown select for PageSize in  my Asp.net Core project but I am facing a problem. I followed Microsoft tutorial for pagination and I managed to to add Next and Previous button. It also keeps the page=2 and the filter I enter , but when i select PageSize to display 20 table rows (other than standar 10) resets all the filters and the current pagination. I need some help on how to add a PageSize selection the proper way so it can displays also filters and page.

Controller :

```
 public class AppUsersController : Controller
    {
        private readonly PushNotificationContext _context;

        public AppUsersController(PushNotificationContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: AppUsers
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(String currentId, string searchId,
                                                String currentTotalCalls, string searchTotalCalls,
                                                string currentLastCall, string searchLastCall,
                                                string currentLatestPush, string searchLatestPush,
                                                string currentFilter, string searchString,
                                                string currentDate, string searchDate,                                              
                                                DateTime? start, DateTime? end,                                               
                                                int? pageNumber,
                                                int PS,
                                                string searchPageSize, string currentPageSize,
                                                string p = null)
        {
            int pageSize = 10;
            int num = _context.AppUsers.Count();           
            var appusers = from a in _context.AppUsers
                            select a;
            var appid = from aid in _context.AppUsers
                           select aid;


       
            //If Search For Adding PageNumber + searchFilter in Url
            if (searchString != null)
            {
                pageNumber = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchString = currentFilter;
            }

            if (searchId != null)
            {
                pageNumber = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchId = currentId;
            }

            if (searchTotalCalls != null)
            {
                pageNumber = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchTotalCalls = currentTotalCalls;
            }

            //Filters Text the Database
            ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                appusers = appusers.Where(s => s.Surname.Contains(searchString)
                               || s.FirstName.Contains(searchString));

                num = appusers.Where(s => s.Surname.Contains(searchString)
                               || s.FirstName.Contains(searchString)).Count();


            }

            ViewData["CurrentId"] = searchId;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchId))
            {
                var ToId = Int32.Parse(searchId);

                appusers = appusers.Where(s => s.Id.ToString().Contains(searchId));

                num = appusers.Where(s => s.Id.ToString().Contains(searchId)).Count();
            }

            ViewData["CurrentTotalCalls"] = searchTotalCalls;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTotalCalls))
            {
                var ToId = Int32.Parse(searchTotalCalls);

                appusers = appusers.Where(s => s.TotalCalls.ToString().Contains(searchTotalCalls));

                num = appusers.Where(s => s.TotalCalls.ToString().Contains(searchTotalCalls)).Count();
                
            }

            ViewData["currentPageSize"] = searchPageSize;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchPageSize))
            {
                pageSize = Int32.Parse(searchPageSize);
           
            }
           
      
            ViewData["currentLastCall"] = searchLastCall;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchLastCall))
            {
                DateTime dtLastCall = DateTime.Parse(searchLastCall);

                appusers = appusers.Where(s => s.LastCall >= dtLastCall.Date && s.LastCall < dtLastCall.AddDays(1));

                num = appusers.Where(s => s.LastCall >= dtLastCall.Date && s.LastCall < dtLastCall.AddDays(1)).Count();

            }

            ViewData["CurrentLatestPush"] = searchLatestPush;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchLatestPush))
            {
                DateTime dtLatestPush = DateTime.Parse(searchLatestPush);


                appusers = appusers.Where(s => s.PushUpdate >= dtLatestPush.Date && s.PushUpdate < dtLatestPush.AddDays(1));

                num = appusers.Where(s => s.PushUpdate>= dtLatestPush.Date && s.PushUpdate < dtLatestPush.AddDays(1)).Count();

            }



            // Populate DropDownList 
            ViewData["CurrentS"] = PS;
            if (PS == 10 )
            {
                pageSize = 10;
            }else if(PS == 20)
            {
                pageSize = 20;
            }
            else if(PS == 50)
            {
                pageSize = 50;
            }


            //Page Size Display Calculations
            ViewBag.Count = num;
            if (pageSize > num)
            {
                ViewBag.Count = num;
                ViewBag.pSize = num;
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Count = num;
                ViewBag.pSize = pageSize;
            }

            //PageNumber bellow 0 becames 1 , Error sovled
            if (pageNumber == 0){
                pageNumber = 1;
            };



            return View(await PushNotificationApp.PaginatedList<AppUser>.CreateAsync(appusers.AsNoTracking(), appid.AsNoTracking(), pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize));
        }
```

Index Page :

```
@model PaginatedList<PushNotificationApp.Models.AppUser>


@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}


@*Header With Filter Top*@
<div class="Application-header">

    @*Header*@
    <h1 class="display-5">PUSH NOTIFICATION APPLICATION</h1>

    @*Date Filter Top*@
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "AppUsers", new { id = "filterForm" }))
        {
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <span class="font-weight-bold">Start Date :</span> <input type="date" name="start">

                <span class="font-weight-bold m-3">End Date :</span> <input type="date" name="end" />

                <span class="font-weight-bold m-3">Trips :</span> <input size="3" type="text" name="SearchTrips" value="@ViewData["CurrentTrips"]" />

                @*<input class="l MainButton" type="submit" value="" OnClick="Button1_Click" />*@

                <button class="m-3" type="submit" value="submit" OnClick="Button1_Click">
                    <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-search" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10.442 10.442a1 1 0 0 1 1.415 0l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 1-1.414 1.415l-3.85-3.85a1 1 0 0 1 0-1.415z" />
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M6.5 12a5.5 5.5 0 1 0 0-11 5.5 5.5 0 0 0 0 11zM13 6.5a6.5 6.5 0 1 1-13 0 6.5 6.5 0 0 1 13 0z" />
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </div>
        }
    <div>
        <!-- Paging Size DropDown -->
        <form asp-action="Index" method="get">
            <select id="PageSelection" name="PS" value="@ViewData["CurrentP"]">
                <option value="">Size</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="50">50</option>
            </select>
            @*<button type="submit">Ho</button>*@
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>


@*Declare next - Prev for footer table*@
@{
    var prevDisabled = !Model.HasPreviousPage ? "disabled" : "";
    var nextDisabled = !Model.HasNextPage ? "disabled" : "";
}





@*2 Flex Tables*@
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color:lightgray; padding:0px!important;">

            <div class="table-container ">

                @*First Table with Data*@
                <table class="table">

                    <thead class=" Left-Table-Header">
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <p>CHECK</p>
                                <form asp-action="Index" method="get">
                                    <div class="form-actions no-color">
                                        <p><input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" /></p>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <p>ID</p>
                                <form asp-action="Index" asp-route-currentFilter="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]" method="get">
                                    <div class="form-actions no-color">
                                        <p><input  size="2" type="text" name="SearchId" value="@ViewData["CurrentId"]" /></p>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </th>
                            <th colspan="4">
                                <p>NAME</p>
                                <form asp-action="Index" method="get">
                                    <div class="form-actions no-color">
                                        <p><input size="20" type="text" name="SearchString" value="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]" /></p>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </th>
                            <th colspan="2">
                                <p>TOTAL CALLS</p>
                                <div>
                                    <form asp-action="Index" method="get">
                                        <div class="form-actions no-color">
                                            <p><input size="3" type="text" name="searchTotalCalls" value="@ViewData["CurrentTotalCalls"]" /></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </th>
                            <th colspan="2">
                                <p>LAST CALL</p>
                                <form asp-action="Index" method="get">
                                    <div class="form-actions no-color">
                                        <p><input size="8" type="text" name="SearchLastCall" value="@ViewData["CurrentLastCall"]" /> </p>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </th>
                            <th colspan="2">
                                <p>LATEST PUSH</p>
                                <form asp-action="Index" method="get">
                                    <div class="form-actions no-color">
                                        <p><input size="8" type="text" name="SearchLatestPush" value="@ViewData["CurrentLatestPush"]" /></p>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>


                    <tbody id="myTable" class="Table-Rows">
                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div id="chex"> <input type="checkbox" id="@item.Id" class="checkBoxes" /> </div>
                                </td>
                                <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)</td>
                                <td colspan="4">
                                    <div onclick="showMore('@item.UserEmail');" id="NameDetails" class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">

                                        <div>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-caret-down-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                                <path d="M7.247 11.14L2.451 5.658C1.885 5.013 2.345 4 3.204 4h9.592a1 1 0 0 1 .753 1.659l-4.796 5.48a1 1 0 0 1-1.506 0z" />
                                            </svg>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                    <div id="@item.UserEmail" style="display:none;">
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Surname)
                                        <br />
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserEmail)
                                        <br />
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MobilePhone)
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td colspan="2">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalCalls)</td>
                                <td colspan="2">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastCall)</td>
                                <td colspan="2"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PushUpdate)</td>

                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>


                </table>

                @*div container with pagination*@
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">

                    @* Prev Next Buttons*@
                    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">
                        <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
                            <ul class="pagination">
                                <li class="page-item">
                                    <a class="page-link MainButton" asp-action="Index"
                                       asp-route-pageNumber="@(Model.PageIndex - 1)"
                                       asp-route-currentFilter="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]"
                                       asp-route-currentId="@ViewData["CurrentId"]"
                                       asp-route-currentTotalCalls="@ViewData["CurrentTotalCalls"]"
                                       asp-route-currentLastCall="@ViewData["CurrentLastCall"]"
                                       asp-route-currentLatestPush="@ViewData["CurrentLatestPush"]"
                                       asp-route-currentPageSize="@ViewData["CurrentPageSize"]"
                                       class="page-link @prevDisabled">
                                        Previous
                                    </a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="page-item">
                                    <a class="page-link MainButton" asp-action="Index"
                                       asp-route-pageNumber="@(Model.PageIndex + 1)"
                                       asp-route-currentFilter="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]"
                                       asp-route-currentId="@ViewData["CurrentId"]"
                                       asp-route-currentTotalCalls="@ViewData["CurrentTotalCalls"]"
                                       asp-route-currentLastCall="@ViewData["CurrentLastCall"]"
                                       asp-route-currentLatestPush="@ViewData["CurrentLatestPush"]"
                                       asp-route-currentPageSize="@ViewData["CurrentPageSize"]"
                                       class="btn btn-default @nextDisabled">
                                        Next
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>





                    @*Table total entries and rows*@
                    @{
                        int data = ViewBag.Count;
                        var i = (Model.PageIndex);
                        var y = ViewBag.pSize;

                        if (data < y) { y = data; } else { y = y * i; }
                    }
                    <p><b>@y</b> out of <b>@data</b></p>

                    @*Clear Button*@
                    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">
                        <a asp-action="Index" class="MainButton">Clear</a>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        @*This is the second Table aligned Flex*@
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lightgray; padding:0px!important; border-left: 1px solid white;">

            <div class="text-area">
                <table id="myTable" class="table">
                    <thead class="Right-Table-Header">
                        <tr>
                            <th> <span class="Right-Table-Header-Text">PUSH NOTIFICATION MESSAGE</span></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><textarea class="txtArea" id="textAreaMSG" name="w3review" rows="10" cols="60">Enter the text you want to sent as a Push Notification...</textarea></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <thead class="Right-Table-Header">
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class="Right-Table-Ready-Msg">READY MESSAGES</span></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @*Radio Boxes With Ready Msg*@
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-check RadioBoxes">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="Radio1" value="option1" onclick="radioMsg()">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="Radio1" id="radioMessage1">Bravo!You have the most trips this Week.</label>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-check RadioBoxes">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="Radio2" value="option2" onclick="radioMsg()">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="Radio2" id="radioMessage2">You travelled a lot this Month!</label>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-check RadioBoxes">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="Radio3" value="option3" onclick="radioMsg()">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="Radio3" id="radioMessage3">Congratulations!You have the most trips this Year.</label>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>

                            @*Push/Push history Buttons*@
                            <td class="d-flex justify-content-between">

                                @*Push History button*@
                                <a class="MainButton" asp-area="" asp-controller="AppUsers" asp-action="Index1">Push History</a>

                                @*Push Button with confirmation box*@
                                <button type="button" class="MainButtonPush" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" onclick="getText()">
                                    Push
                                </button>
                                <!-- Modal -->
                                <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Push Notification Confirmation</h5>
                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-body" id="modal_body_text">
                                                Are are about to sent Push Notification to ... with the following text : ....
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-between">
                                                <button type="button" class="MainButton" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                <button class="MainButtonPush" onclick="myf()">Push</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know I have many things I need to solve to have a complete clean code and some parts are useless but I am a beginner and I am trying to learn

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Rena , It actually works fine when I go to next page and keeps the PS=20 on link. The only issue is that when I add a Filter it resets the PS value and if I change PS value after it resets the Filter. Is it possible to be fixed ? I couldn't find a tutorial to help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit in a mess.

1.Your view contains `@ViewData["CurrentP"]` but in your action is `@ViewData["CurrentS"]`.

2.The code below is not used to populate DropDownList:

```
// Populate DropDownList 
ViewData["CurrentS"] = PS;
if (PS == 10 )
{
    pageSize = 10;
}else if(PS == 20)
{
    pageSize = 20;
}
else if(PS == 50)
{
    pageSize = 50;
}
```

You have hard-coded the DropDownList in razor view:

```
Paging Size DropDown
<form asp-action="Index" method="get">
    <select id="PageSelection" name="PS" value="@ViewData["CurrentS"]">
        <option value="">Size</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Ho</button>
</form>
```

3.In official document,`PaginatedList` method contains three paramaters,not sure why do you pass four paramater,and both of the `appid` and `appusers` are the same object.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-5.0#add-paging-to-students-index

I have changed your code and provide the working code below:

View:

```
@model PaginatedList<AppUser>    
Header With Filter Top
<div class="Application-header">  
    Header
    <h1 class="display-5">PUSH NOTIFICATION APPLICATION</h1> 
    Date Filter Top
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "AppUsers", new { id = "filterForm" }))
        {
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <span class="font-weight-bold">Start Date :</span> <input type="date" name="start">

                <span class="font-weight-bold m-3">End Date :</span> <input type="date" name="end" />

                <span class="font-weight-bold m-3">Trips :</span> <input size="3" type="text" name="SearchTrips" value="@ViewData["CurrentTrips"]" />

                <input class="l MainButton" type="submit" value="" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

                <button class="m-3" type="submit" value="submit" OnClick="Button1_Click">
                    <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-search" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10.442 10.442a1 1 0 0 1 1.415 0l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 1-1.414 1.415l-3.85-3.85a1 1 0 0 1 0-1.415z" />
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M6.5 12a5.5 5.5 0 1 0 0-11 5.5 5.5 0 0 0 0 11zM13 6.5a6.5 6.5 0 1 1-13 0 6.5 6.5 0 0 1 13 0z" />
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </div>
        }
        <div>
            Paging Size DropDown
            <form asp-action="Index" method="get">           //change here....
                <select id="PageSelection" name="PS" value="@ViewData["CurrentS"]">
                    <option value="">Size</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="20">20</option>
                    <option value="50">50</option>
                </select>
                <button type="submit">Ho</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
Declare next - Prev for footer table
@{
    var prevDisabled = !Model.HasPreviousPage ? "disabled" : "";
    var nextDisabled = !Model.HasNextPage ? "disabled" : "";
}  
            2 Flex Tables
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color:lightgray; padding:0px!important;">

            <div class="table-container ">

                First Table with Data
                <table class="table">

                    <thead class=" Left-Table-Header">
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <p>CHECK</p>
                                <form asp-action="Index" method="get">
                                    <div class="form-actions no-color">
                                        <p><input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" /></p>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <p>ID</p>
                                <form asp-action="Index" asp-route-currentFilter="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]" method="get">
                                    <div class="form-actions no-color">
                                        <p><input size="2" type="text" name="SearchId" value="@ViewData["CurrentId"]" /></p>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </th>
                            <th colspan="4">
                                <p>NAME</p>
                                <form asp-action="Index" method="get">
                                    <div class="form-actions no-color">
                                        <p><input size="20" type="text" name="SearchString" value="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]" /></p>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </th>
                            <th colspan="2">
                                <p>TOTAL CALLS</p>
                                <div>
                                    <form asp-action="Index" method="get">
                                        <div class="form-actions no-color">
                                            <p><input size="3" type="text" name="searchTotalCalls" value="@ViewData["CurrentTotalCalls"]" /></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </th>
                            <th colspan="2">
                                <p>LAST CALL</p>
                                <form asp-action="Index" method="get">
                                    <div class="form-actions no-color">
                                        <p><input size="8" type="text" name="SearchLastCall" value="@ViewData["CurrentLastCall"]" /> </p>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </th>
                            <th colspan="2">
                                <p>LATEST PUSH</p>
                                <form asp-action="Index" method="get">
                                    <div class="form-actions no-color">
                                        <p><input size="8" type="text" name="SearchLatestPush" value="@ViewData["CurrentLatestPush"]" /></p>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>


                    <tbody id="myTable" class="Table-Rows">
                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div id="chex"> <input type="checkbox" id="@item.Id" class="checkBoxes" /> </div>
                                </td>
                                <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)</td>
                                <td colspan="4">
                                    <div onclick="showMore('@item.UserEmail');" id="NameDetails" class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">

                                        <div>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-caret-down-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                                <path d="M7.247 11.14L2.451 5.658C1.885 5.013 2.345 4 3.204 4h9.592a1 1 0 0 1 .753 1.659l-4.796 5.48a1 1 0 0 1-1.506 0z" />
                                            </svg>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                    <div id="@item.UserEmail" style="display:none;">
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Surname)
                                        <br />
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserEmail)
                                        <br />
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MobilePhone)
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td colspan="2">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalCalls)</td>
                                <td colspan="2">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastCall)</td>
                                <td colspan="2"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PushUpdate)</td>

                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>


                </table>

                div container with pagination
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">

                    Prev Next Buttons
                    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">
                        <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
                            <ul class="pagination">
                                <li class="page-item">
                                    <a class="page-link MainButton" asp-action="Index"
                                       asp-route-pageNumber="@(Model.PageIndex - 1)"
                                       asp-route-currentFilter="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]"
                                       asp-route-currentId="@ViewData["CurrentId"]"
                                       asp-route-currentTotalCalls="@ViewData["CurrentTotalCalls"]"
                                       asp-route-currentLastCall="@ViewData["CurrentLastCall"]"
                                       asp-route-currentLatestPush="@ViewData["CurrentLatestPush"]"
                                       asp-route-currentPageSize="@ViewData["CurrentPageSize"]"
                                       class="page-link @prevDisabled">
                                        Previous
                                    </a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="page-item">
                                    <a class="page-link MainButton" asp-action="Index"
                                       asp-route-pageNumber="@(Model.PageIndex + 1)"
                                       asp-route-currentFilter="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]"
                                       asp-route-currentId="@ViewData["CurrentId"]"
                                       asp-route-currentTotalCalls="@ViewData["CurrentTotalCalls"]"
                                       asp-route-currentLastCall="@ViewData["CurrentLastCall"]"
                                       asp-route-currentLatestPush="@ViewData["CurrentLatestPush"]"
                                       asp-route-currentPageSize="@ViewData["CurrentPageSize"]"
                                       class="btn btn-default @nextDisabled">
                                        Next
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                    Table total entries and rows
                    @{
                        int data = ViewBag.Count;
                        var i = (Model.PageIndex);
                        var y = ViewBag.pSize;

                        if (data < y) { y = data; } else { y = y * i; }
                    }
                    <p><b>@y</b> out of <b>@data</b></p>

                    Clear Button
                    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">
                        <a asp-action="Index" class="MainButton">Clear</a>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        This is the second Table aligned Flex
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lightgray; padding:0px!important; border-left: 1px solid white;">

            <div class="text-area">
                <table id="myTable" class="table">
                    <thead class="Right-Table-Header">
                        <tr>
                            <th> <span class="Right-Table-Header-Text">PUSH NOTIFICATION MESSAGE</span></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><textarea class="txtArea" id="textAreaMSG" name="w3review" rows="10" cols="60">Enter the text you want to sent as a Push Notification...</textarea></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <thead class="Right-Table-Header">
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class="Right-Table-Ready-Msg">READY MESSAGES</span></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        Radio Boxes With Ready Msg
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-check RadioBoxes">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="Radio1" value="option1" onclick="radioMsg()">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="Radio1" id="radioMessage1">Bravo!You have the most trips this Week.</label>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-check RadioBoxes">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="Radio2" value="option2" onclick="radioMsg()">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="Radio2" id="radioMessage2">You travelled a lot this Month!</label>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-check RadioBoxes">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="Radio3" value="option3" onclick="radioMsg()">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="Radio3" id="radioMessage3">Congratulations!You have the most trips this Year.</label>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>

                            Push/Push history Buttons
                            <td class="d-flex justify-content-between">

                                Push History button
                                <a class="MainButton" asp-area="" asp-controller="AppUsers" asp-action="Index1">Push History</a>

                                Push Button with confirmation box
                                <button type="button" class="MainButtonPush" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" onclick="getText()">
                                    Push
                                </button>
                                Modal
                                <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Push Notification Confirmation</h5>
                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-body" id="modal_body_text">
                                                Are are about to sent Push Notification to ... with the following text : ....
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-between">
                                                <button type="button" class="MainButton" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                <button class="MainButtonPush" onclick="myf()">Push</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(String currentId, string searchId,
                                        String currentTotalCalls, string searchTotalCalls,
                                        string currentLastCall, string searchLastCall,
                                        string currentLatestPush, string searchLatestPush,
                                        string currentFilter, string searchString,
                                        string currentDate, string searchDate,
                                        DateTime? start, DateTime? end,
                                        int? pageNumber,
                                        int PS,
                                        string searchPageSize, int currentPageSize,
                                        string p = null)
{
    int pageSize = 10;
    int num = _context.AppUser.Count();
    var appusers = from a in _context.AppUser
                    select a;
    //var appid = from aid in _context.AppUsers
                       //select aid;
    //If Search For Adding PageNumber + searchFilter in Url
    if (searchString != null)
    {
        pageNumber = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        searchString = currentFilter;
    }

    if (searchId != null)
    {
        pageNumber = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        searchId = currentId;
    }

    if (searchTotalCalls != null)
    {
        pageNumber = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        searchTotalCalls = currentTotalCalls;
    }
    //Filters Text the Database
    ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        //do your stuff...
    }
    ViewData["CurrentId"] = searchId;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchId))
    {
        //do your stuff...
    }
    ViewData["CurrentTotalCalls"] = searchTotalCalls;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTotalCalls))
    {
        //do your stuff...
    }

    //Begin of change
    if (PS!=0|| currentPageSize!=0)
    {
        if(PS==0)
        {
            ViewData["CurrentPageSize"] = currentPageSize;
            pageSize = currentPageSize;
        }
        else
        {
            ViewData["CurrentPageSize"] = PS;
            pageSize = PS;
        }

    }

    //ViewData["currentPageSize"] = searchPageSize;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchPageSize))
    {
        ViewData["CurrentPageSize"] = searchPageSize;
        pageSize = Int32.Parse(searchPageSize);
    }
    if(ViewData["CurrentPageSize"] !=null)
    {
        pageSize = Int32.Parse(ViewData["CurrentPageSize"].ToString());
    }
    //End of change

    ViewData["currentLastCall"] = searchLastCall;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchLastCall))
    {
        //do your stuff...
    }
    ViewData["CurrentLatestPush"] = searchLatestPush;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchLatestPush))
    {       
        //do your stuff...
    }
    //The code below is useless

    // Populate DropDownList 
    //ViewData["CurrentS"] = PS;
    //if (PS == 10)
    //{
    //    pageSize = 10;
    //}
    //else if (PS == 20)
    //{
    //    pageSize = 20;
    //}
    //else if (PS == 50)
    //{
    //    pageSize = 50;
    //}


    //Page Size Display Calculations
    ViewBag.Count = num;
    if (pageSize > num)
    {
        ViewBag.Count = num;
        ViewBag.pSize = num;
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Count = num;
        ViewBag.pSize = pageSize;
    }

    //PageNumber bellow 0 becames 1 , Error sovled
    if (pageNumber == 0)
    {
        pageNumber = 1;
    };

    return View(await PaginatedList<AppUser>.CreateAsync(appusers.AsNoTracking(),  pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize));
}
```

PaginatedList:

```
public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>
{
    public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; private set; }

    public PaginatedList(List<T> items, int count, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        PageIndex = pageIndex;
        TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);

        this.AddRange(items);
    }

    public bool HasPreviousPage
    {
        get
        {
            return (PageIndex > 1);
        }
    }

    public bool HasNextPage
    {
        get
        {
            return (PageIndex < TotalPages);
        }
    }

    public static async Task<PaginatedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        var count = source.Count();
        var items = source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
        return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Rena , It actually works fine when I go to next page and keeps the PS=20 on link. The only issue is that when I add a Filter it resets the PS value and if I change PS value after it resets the Filter. Is it possible to be fixed ? I couldn't find a tutorial to help me with that.

Comment: Hi @AridTrade,Tutorial is here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-5.0.I suggest that you could follow this tutorial because your code behind is a big in a mess now.